# is Object.create() method performs shallow copy?

Tags: javascript, scratchpad

I am newbee to JavaScript. When I read the Object.create documentation, it is written like 'The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing object' (Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). It do not mention anything about the shallow copy of the object. But when I experimented with below script, I confirmed that, create method is performing shallow copy.

```
var foo = {
  a : 100,
  details : {
    version : 1.1,
    name : 'Demo of object inheritance'
  },

  printInfo : function(){
    console.log(this.details.version);
    console.log(this.details.name);
    console.log(this.a);
  }

}

var bar = Object.create(foo);

foo.printInfo();
bar.printInfo();

console.log("\n Updating the details and property a of bar object");

bar.details.version = 2.2;
bar.details.name = "Bar object changed the name";
bar.a = 123456;

console.log("\n")
foo.printInfo();
bar.printInfo();
```

Is my understanding correct? Please point to me any documentation that confirms create() method performs shallow copy.

When I executed in Scratchpad, I seen below output in console.

```
1.1
Demo of object inheritance
100
1.1
Demo of object inheritance
100

Updating the details and property a of bar object Scratchpad/1:21:1


2.2
Bar object changed the name
100
2.2
Bar object changed the name
123456
```

Comment: It doesn't copy the passed object at all, instead it sets the *internal prototype* of the newly created object to the passed object.

Comment: nope, its just create the same object.
if you want to clone it u can use new es6 {...object}

Comment: You forgot to quote the most important part *"[...] using an existing object **to provide the newly created object's `__proto__`** ."* Granted, it's not the best description, but it's a community owned wiki after all. *edit:* I updated the description.

Comment: But in my example, details is not a prototype property, it is the foo object property itself. But when I changed the bar.details, it is reflecting in foo.details also...any reason for this.

Comment: Objects are reference-type and mutable values. When you create an object, you really get a reference to a memory location. Mutating an object has the effect that any reference "reflects" the new state of the object. Simplest example: `var foo = {}; var bar = foo; foo.baz = 21; console.log(bar);`. A prototype is just another object. In your example, `bar` has an *internal* reference to `foo`. If you don't quite understand prototypes yet, I recommend https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/0cc17c53ff772e20dfd6a7072c965df2486116e8/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to with shallow copy.
Instead, you have figure it out how **Prototype Inheritance** works in Javascript world.

To have a better understanding, let's break this down into following 2 parts:

**Reading property from child object:**

When you try to access a property from a child object, Javascript parser will try to search through up prototype chain until it manages to find it else return undefined if not found.

**Write property in child object**

It will first try to locate that the object to which the your targeted property belongs, and then directly set that property on that object.

### Let's take part of your code as example:

---

**bar.details.version = 2.2;**

```
 What Javascript parser does:
```

1. First, **details** will be located through **prototype chain** searching and it will be found on **foo** (ie: **bar.details === foo.details**)
2. Second, **version** is directly set on **details** object(that's why **this.details.version** and **this.details.name** are both "unexpectedly" changed as you saw in your result and as a result **bar.details.version === foo.details.version === 2.2**))

---

**bar.a = 123456;**

```
What Javascript parser does:
```

Before anything gets started, **bar** is already located and there's **no need** to search though prototype chain, as a result, **a** will be **directly** set on the **bar**
(ie. that's why only bar.a is affected with **foo.a** still holding the origin value:**123456**)

Answer (score 3):

`Object.Create` does not copy anything at all, it just sets 
the passed object as the prototype of a new object:

```
const person = {name: 'Alex', age: 29}
const newPerson = Object.create(person)

console.log(newPerson)
```

[image]

In order to make a shallow copy, you can use `Object.assign`.

```
const newPersonObj = Object.assign({}, person)
console.log(newPersonObj)
```

This will create entirely new copy.
[image]

Comment: Hi Sandip, Are you tried with nested object. I observed, it is performing shallow copy....

Comment: @HariKrishna: As has been said a couple of times, and as has been shown in this answer, `Object.create` does *not* create a copy at all.

Comment: It took me a while to grasp that. IMHO, as the answer below says, the key to understanding it is to 'figure out how Prototype inheritance works'.

Answer (score -1):

> create method is performing shallow copy.

-- **EDIT** --

Nope, it may seem that way but the term *shallow copy* would be inaccurate. It would be more in line with **prototypal inheritance** [MDN article here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Given an object `oA` that has a `name` property, function `Object.create(oA)` creates a new object `oB`. Trying to access property `oB.name` would look up the prototype chain until it finds one on its prototype at `oA.name`.

Sample code below:

```js
/* create one object adam */
const adam = {
 name: 'Adam',
} 
console.log(`does adam have own 'name' property?`, adam.hasOwnProperty('name')) // true

/* create new object bob, whose prototype 'ancestor' is adam */
const bob = Object.create(adam)
console.log(`does bob have own 'name' property? (1)`, bob.hasOwnProperty('name')) // false; the 'name' prop is on adam

/* assigning 'name' on bob doesn't change adam's name, it just 'shadows' it -- accessing 'name' on bob returns the one on bob */
bob.name = 'Bob'
console.log(`does bob have own 'name' property? (2)`, bob.hasOwnProperty('name')) // now true

/* adam and bob now each have their own 'name' property */
console.log(adam.name) // Adam
console.log(bob.name)  // Bob

/* show the relationship of adam and bob */
console.log(`is adam a prototype 'ancestor' of bob?`, adam.isPrototypeOf(bob)) // true, linked via Object.create()
console.log(`is bob a prototype 'ancestor' of adam?`, bob.isPrototypeOf(adam)) // false, the prototype points one way
```

Hope this helps. Cheers,

Comment: Its not a "clone" and your "rule of thumb" certainly makes no sense at all.

Comment: @JonasWilms I must disagree, the word 'clone' is a sufficient metaphor in this case. As per [MDN Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create): "The Object.create() method creates a new object...".

Comment: Your answer is misleading. Your "own" and "shared" properties comparison is incorrect. Here would be a more fair example: `ob.hobbies = ['dining']`. This will also modify "the clone's property", and not the original, even though the value is a reference type. As for *"the clone will have its own properties that are value type (ie string, int, bool)"* Nope: `Object.create({baz: 21}).hasOwnProperty('baz'); // false`. The value of the properties is almost irrelevant for explaining how prototypes work. More interesting is the result of `obj.hasOwnProperty(...)`.

Comment: @FelixKling I see your point. Yup you're right the accurate answer should have led to prototype chains. I have edited my answer to reflect this, thanks.